# Array of pairs, gibberish output (unallocated memory?)

Tags: c++

Coming from Java I was trying to implement a simple Battleships game in C++ but already got stuck at this Array:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

class Ship{
    private:
        int length;
        bool direction; //false = left, true = down
        pair <int,int> coords[];
    public:
        Ship(int x, int y, bool, int);
        void printship();
};

Ship::Ship(int x, int y, bool dir, int l){ 
    pair <int,int> coords[l];
    length = l;
    if (dir){
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++){
            coords[i] = make_pair(x, y+i);
        }   
    }   
    else{
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++){
            coords[i] = make_pair(x+i, y); 
        }   
    }   
}
void Ship::printship(){
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        cout << "x: " << coords[i].first << ", y: " << coords[i].second << endl;
    }   
}

int main(){
    Ship tests(2,3,true,3);
    tests.printship();
    return 0;
}
```

What I get is:

```
x: 134515168, y: 0
x: 0, y: 9938131
x: 1, y: -1080624940
```

I guess something is pointing to unallocated memory, but I can't figure out what, and why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two different variables both called `coords`. One is a private member variable, the other is local to the constructor. Because the local variable you create in the constructor shadows the member variable, the constructor never initializes the member variable.

Try this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Ship{
    private:
        int length;
        bool direction; //false = left, true = down
        vector< pair <int,int> > coords; // *** CHANGE HERE
    public:
        Ship(int x, int y, bool, int);
        void printship();
};

Ship::Ship(int x, int y, bool dir, int l){ 
    length = l;
    if (dir){
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++){
            coords.push_back(make_pair(x, y+i)); // *** CHANGE HERE
        }   
    }   
    else{
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++){
            coords.push_back(make_pair(x+i, y)); // *** CHANGE HERE
        }   
    }   
}
void Ship::printship(){
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        cout << "x: " << coords[i].first << ", y: " << coords[i].second << endl;
    }   
}

int main(){
    Ship tests(2,3,true,3);
    tests.printship();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, ok, I get it. I can't have the Array only get a size at Runtime. I considered using Vectors but I thought it would be possible with an Array too. Thanks!

Comment: It is, but it's much harder that way. You'll basically wind up re-implementing `vector`.

Comment: @1nterference: you should accept his answer by clicking on the tick below the voting arrows.

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor you have a local variable `coords` which you initialize instead of your member variable. Also you should probably a a `vector` instead of an array because then you do not need to worry about allocating and releasing memory:

```
class Ship{
private:
    bool direction; //false = left, true = down
    vector<pair<int,int>> coords;
public:
    Ship(int x, int y, bool, int);
    void printship();
};

Ship::Ship(int x, int y, bool dir, int l){ 
    if (dir){
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++){
           coords.push_back(make_pair(x, y+i));
        }   
    }   
    else{
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++){
           coords.push_back(make_pair(x+i, y)); 
        }   
    }   
}

void Ship::printship(){
    for (vector<pair<int, int>>::iterator it = coords.begin(); it != coords.end(); ++it)
        cout << "x: " << it->first << ", y: " << it->second << endl;
    }   
}
```